# How does arma::find_unique determine unique indices?

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo

I am using `arma::find_unique`, and I thought it returned the index of the first occurrence of each unique value in a vector, but it appears to return something else.

Here is a toy function:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec test(arma::vec& x_) {
  vec x=arma::sort(x_);
  return arma::find_unique(x);
}
```

If I run the function in R with a simple vector `test(5:1)` I get a vector of all the indices `0,1,2,3,4` which makes sense since each value is unique.

If I try something like:

```
set.seed(1991)
var=sample(1:8,20,TRUE)
test(var)
```

OUTPUT:

> 1,3,6,7,19,12,14,18.

All those values make sense except the first one. Why is the first unique value at index 1 and not 0? Clearly I am misunderstanding what `arma::find_unique` intends to do so I would appreciate if someone could enlighten me.

**EDIT**
My session information

[image: sessionInfo()]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the following is courtesy of @nrussell, the man is amazing, and was given in the comments to this "answer." (I do not deserve the check mark nor upvotes.)

> Actually, I'm pretty sure this is all just a misinterpretation of the Armadillo documentation, which never actually guarantees that a stable sort is used, as @Carl was expecting. Underneath, std::sort is [`being called`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/c85985e243efb3179beafe9f309597758659bb3c/inst/include/armadillo_bits/op_find_unique_meat.hpp#L71), which **is not guaranteed to be a stable sort** by the C++ standard; also stated [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):
>
> > *"The order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved."*
>
> I can demonstrate this [here](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/9a77e000f3e86386a6f31796d3d92169), replicating the ["packet" structure](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/6450efdb9b727539dabd13467db5a7a0f25c8b38/inst/include/armadillo_bits/op_find_unique_bones.hpp#L29-L47) use in the Armadillo's algorithm. My guess is that `libc++` (typically used by OS X) does implement `std::sort` as a stable sort, while `libstdc++` does not.

My turn: The stable sort, or maintaining the relative order of records with equal keys (i.e. values), is the key issue behind this question. For example, consider the following:

```
dog car pool dig
```

Sorting by the first letter with a **stable** sort gives us:

```
car dog dig pool
```

Because the word "dog" appeared prior to "dig" in the vector, it therefore must appear before "dig" in the output.

Sorting by the first letter with a **unstable** sort gives us:

```
car dig dog pool
```

or

```
car dog dig pool
```

The principal is relevant to numbers since each key generate is literally present elsewhere. So, we have:

```
2, 3, 2, 4
```

Thus, when the unique values are found:

```
2, 3, 4
```

The 2 can take id either 0 or 2.

As @nrussell explained, macOS since OS X Mavericks (10.9) relies by default on `--stdlib=libc++` vs. the traditional `--stdlib=libstdc++` flag for compiling. This was likely the reason why I was unable to replicate it as one implementation opts for stability while the other does not.

## Original Answer

First, I'm not able to replicate this on macOS... (See end)

It seems as if we are able to repro this on Linux though (@nrussel). Which means at some point, there is an issue given in the linked code.

Secondly, [arma::find_unique](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find_unique) is implemented [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/c85985e243efb3179beafe9f309597758659bb3c/inst/include/armadillo_bits/fn_find_unique.hpp) using [matrix ops](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/6450efdb9b727539dabd13467db5a7a0f25c8b38/inst/include/armadillo_bits/mtOp_meat.hpp) with [op_find_unique](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/6450efdb9b727539dabd13467db5a7a0f25c8b38/inst/include/armadillo_bits/op_find_unique_bones.hpp). The later is the key as it implements the comparators.

Thus, in short, there should be no way that is possible given that you sort the vector and the first item is always considered to be unique.

## Test function

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec test(arma::vec& x_) {
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Input:" << x_.t() << std::endl;
    arma::vec x = arma::sort(x_);
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Sorted:" << x.t() << std::endl;
    arma::uvec o = arma::find_unique(x);
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Indices:" << o.t() << std::endl;
    return o;
}
    
/*** R
set.seed(1991)
(v=sample(1:8,20,TRUE))
## [1] 2 2 1 5 7 6 7 6 4 1 5 3 1 4 4 2 8 7 7 8
sort(v)
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8

test(v)
### Received
##    2.0000   2.0000   1.0000   5.0000   7.0000   6.0000   7.0000   6.0000   4.0000   1.0000   5.0000   3.0000   1.0000   4.0000   4.0000   2.0000   8.0000   7.0000   7.0000   8.0000

### Sorted
## 1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   2.0000   2.0000   2.0000   3.0000   4.0000   4.0000   4.0000   5.0000   5.0000   6.0000   6.0000   7.0000   7.0000   7.0000   7.0000   8.0000   8.0000

### Output
## 0    3    6    7   10   12   14   18
*/
```

Comment: Thanks @Coatless. I was debugging with `Rcout` the same way. I am using Windows and I swear I get a 1 and not a 0

Comment: @Carl, run the above code chunk. Post a screenshot of your results.

Comment: @carl also add `library(RcppArmadillo);sessionInfo()`

Comment: @Coatless On Linux I am able to reproduce OP's issue, e.g. when I run `test(v)[,1]` I get `1  3  6  7 10 12 14 18`. This is not the case for you?

Comment: @nrussell Not able to repo this case at all under  R 3.3.1 + Armadillo 7.200.2.0 or R 3.2.2 + Armadillo 7.200.2.0. Results in the above answer.

Comment: I am happy to run with debug if you explain how to do so on Windows. Running `R --debugger=gdb` gives me an warning saying unknown option. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Carl just need the above code snippet under test function to be ran. I'll try throwing this in a VM otherwise.

Comment: Gotcha, will do soon

Comment: It'll be a few minutes before I can get a screenshot, but I tell you now that my output is identical to yours except the first value of the output is 1.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure this is all just a misinterpretation of the Armadillo documentation, which never actually guarantees that a stable sort is used, as @Carl was expecting. Underneath, `std::sort` is [being called](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/c85985e243efb3179beafe9f309597758659bb3c/inst/include/armadillo_bits/op_find_unique_meat.hpp#L71), which **is not guaranteed to be a stable sort** by the C++ standard; also stated [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort): *"The order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved."*

Comment: That makes sense, so ties may switch places when resorted within `arma::find_unique`.

Comment: I can demonstrate this [here](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/9a77e000f3e86386a6f31796d3d92169), replicating the "packet" structure [use in the Armadillo's algorithm](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/6450efdb9b727539dabd13467db5a7a0f25c8b38/inst/include/armadillo_bits/op_find_unique_bones.hpp#L29-L47). My guess is that `libc++` (typically used by OS X) does implement `std::sort` as a stable sort, while `libstdc++` does not.

Comment: @Carl Yes if you notice in the commented out results of my linked example, the first `id` for `value == 2.0` is `1` when using `std::sort`, and `0` when using `std::stable_sort`.

Comment: @nrussell awesome job. I paraphrased and extended the explanation slightly. Though, I would have felt a bit better if you submitted the answer yourself as you were able to correctly diagnose it.

Comment: It's cool; I'm not worried about a little rep here and there. Besides, you took the initiative to write up an answer and provide a good summary, so +1 for that.